# Shape error using Tensorflow (tf.learn, DNNClassifier)

Tags: tensorflow

I've encountered a shape error in tensorflow that I can't figure out.

If I run a basic demo with the iris dataset using tf.learn, it looks like this:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target
>>> x_iris.shape
(150, 4)
>>> y_iris.shape
(150,)
>>> type(x_iris)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Looks good. I run this code:

```
feature_columns = [ tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column( "", dimension = 4 ) ]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier( feature_columns = feature_columns, hidden_units = [ 10, 20, 10 ], n_classes = 3, model_dir = "/tmp/iris_model" )
classifier.fit( x = x_iris, y = y_tiris, steps = 2000 )
```

And it works great! So that's good.

Now, I have the exact same situation with a Titanic dataset I've worked with from over at Kaggle:

```
>>> x_titanic.shape
(700, 14)
>>> y_titanic.shape
(700,)
>>>type(x_titanic)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Same shapes, same types. Should be OK. I run the same code:

```
feature_columns = [ tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column( "", dimension = 14 ) ]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier( feature_columns = feature_columns, hidden_units = [ 10, 20, 10 ], n_classes = 2, model_dir = "/tmp/iris_model" )
classifier.fit( x = x_titanic, y = y_titanic, steps = 2000 )
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 435, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 333, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 662, in _train_model
    train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 963, in _get_train_ops
    _, loss, train_op = self._call_model_fn(features, targets, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 944, in _call_model_fn
    return self._model_fn(features, targets, mode=mode, params=self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 258, in _dnn_classifier_model_fn
    weight=_get_weight_tensor(features, weight_column_name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py", line 329, in sigmoid_cross_entropy
    logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(multi_class_labels.get_shape())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 750, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible
```

Why is this? It looks like there is a problem with the shape of y_titanic:

```
sigmoid_cross_entropy
logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(multi_class_labels.get_shape())
```

due to the fact that it's just binary (0,1), but that's the default for DNNClassifier. Is there something special I have to change? Do I have to tf.one_hot the y vector?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue that may still be getting fixed:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4715

I changed 'n_classes' to 3 and the problem disappeared - got good performance, too! Still not 100% sure *why* this happened.

Looks like the fix was made 11 days ago https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b718fd6ad8cebc470fcc7e53bb6902168edd5587

Which means I have to update my tensorflow...

Answer (score 0):

Go to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and download the latest whl file, will fix this bug.