# tf.contrib.learn Quickstart: - Changing n_classes to 2 does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying out the [tf.contrib.learn Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/index.html#tf-contrib-learn-quickstart), and it works when using the code given in the tutorial. But, if I change the training and test sets to just have 2 classifications (i.e. only 2 iris species), I get the following output and error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Change warning: default value of `enable_centered_bias` will change after 2016-10-09. It will be disabled by default.Instructions for keeping existing behaviour:
Explicitly set `enable_centered_bias` to 'True' if you want to keep existing behaviour.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using default config.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    steps=2000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 435, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 333, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 662, in _train_model
    train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 963, in _get_train_ops
    _, loss, train_op = self._call_model_fn(features, targets, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 944, in _call_model_fn
    return self._model_fn(features, targets, mode=mode, params=self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 258, in _dnn_classifier_model_fn
    weight=_get_weight_tensor(features, weight_column_name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py", line 329, in sigmoid_cross_entropy
    logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(multi_class_labels.get_shape())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 750, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible
```

The only code I've changed is when creating the classifier (changed `n_classes` from 3 to 2):

```
# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=2,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

Could someone please explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same bug and apparently it's a bug from tensorflow, see link below for further information :

[Shape error using Tensorflow (tf.learn, DNNClassifier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193505/shape-error-using-tensorflow-tf-learn-dnnclassifier)

I fixed it with set n_classes to 3 even if I have only 2 classes

Comment: Thank you @sabine!

Comment: This is a problem in r0.11 and will be fixed in r0.12. I think the easiest fix until the next release is to use a virtualenv with r0.10 installed or as suggested using n_classes=3